# How can I change ImageView's image

Tags: android

I want to change other activity's imageView's image how can i do this.I use this code but not working.

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
view.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_banner_statics_icon);
```

Comment: are you getting any error if yes plz share it to make current code working

Comment: no I don't getting error but application not running.

Comment: your code is correct 100% , so add the full stack trace of your error to see what is the real error, may be it is an `OutOfMemorryException` if you are trying to load a Huge Drawable in memory

Comment: ok i will try it,thaks so much

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the `ImageView` of another activity by using this method. Only the activity that created the view can make use of it.

You need to give access to the `ImageView` to the other activity, or create a **callback** into the original activity to change what is shown on screen.